# CMS that allows custom CSS/HTML

Tags: html, wordpress, css, content-management-system

I have an issue. I have made a custom website using CSS and HTML. I want to allow my client to edit and add posts to the website without any knowledge of HTML or CSS while still giving myself the ability to manage the code. Is there any programs or online tools?
I have tried wordpress at (Wordpress.org) and set it up on my website but I was unable to figure out how to use my custom HTML and CSS on the wordpress.

Comment: Wordpress is the industry standard for this. There are many resources that help you with creating your custom Wordpress theme. http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom sites in Wordpress by using the default installation (I think currently it's the "TwentyTwelve theme), and simply copying the files you want to customize into a child theme directory - named anything you want.

Also copy the default CSS into the child theme directory you make. These files will then be what supercedes the default files when you choose yuor child theme in the `Appearance > Themes` menu in the default dashboard.

Comment: I should mention that only the child theme directory can be named anything you want, but DO NOT change the names of the files you copy into the child directory or they won't be used.